# save other website's content and image to database/strucutr

Tags: c#, java, php, asp.net

I am trying to create an "Wenelo fashion shopping" iphone App effect where user submit a link
and it will extract the site data to a structure.

What kind of web/non web technology should I be using for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using a server for the scraping job. You could use jsoup if your server side language will be java, it's a **very** powerful library. For php there are a lot of options out there. I've used Simple HTML DOM Library, which is pretty simple and easy to use, but I'm sure there are others that are better. Check here [HTML Scraping in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120/html-scraping-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do web scraping. You can see a related topic about it on [StackoverFlow over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056/best-library-to-do-web-scraping) You can read more on the technique over at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping.).